# Oracle query creating multiple sessions

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partition, database-partitioning

I am running a select statement, its acquiring 200+ sessions. I am unable to get root cause why it is giving too many connection.

Sample statement:

```
 Select name from tablename where colname=xyz;
```

Table is hash partioned(10 partitions) and index is also hash partitioned(10 partitions).

Answer (score 1):

It is probably caused by parallel execution. Disabling with hint:

```
Select /*+ no_parallel(t)*/ name from tablename t where colname=xyz;

-- disabling on session level
ALTER SESSION DISABLE PARALLEL QUERY;
```

You should check DOP(degree of parallelism) both on table/index level:

```
select owner,table_name, degree
from user_tables
where table_name in ('tablename');

alter table tablename noparallel;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this was not your question, but the number of hash partition should be a power of 2